# Smart way to cluster 'select' output from MariaDB

Tags: sql, node.js, mariadb

Let's say we have the following tables

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS table1 (
    id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    name varchar(64)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS table2 (
    id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    name varchar(64)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS table3 (
    id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    name varchar(64)
);
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS table1_table2 (
    table1Id int NOT NULL,
    table2Id int NOT NULL
    FOREIGN KEY (table1Id) REFERENCES table1 (id),
    FOREIGN KEY (table2Id) REFERENCES table2 (id),
);
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS table1_table3 (
    table1Id int NOT NULL,
    table3Id int NOT NULL
    FOREIGN KEY (table1Id) REFERENCES table1 (id),
    FOREIGN KEY (table3Id) REFERENCES table3 (id),
);
```

Afterwards, I insert one value in `table1`, as well as multiple into `table2` and `table3` (with inserts which link the entries with the tables `table1_table2` and `table1_table3`).
If I try to select everything from the 'non-linking' tables now, I'll get something similar to

```js
[
  {
    table1.id: 1,
    table1.name: 'my-table',
    table2.id: 1,
    table2.name: 'other-table',
    table3.id: 1,
    table3.name: 'something else'
  },
 {
    table1.id: 1,
    table1.name: 'my-table',
    table2.id: 2,
    table2.name: 'new-other-table',
    table3.id: 1,
    table3.name: 'something else'
  }
<...>
]
```

This way the values for table1 and table3 will be repeated multiple times, without any change. It would make much more sense if the values could be combined or clustered in a way. For example:

```sql
[
  {
    table1.id: 1,
    table1.name: 'my-table',
    table2 : [
      {
        table2.id: 1,
        table2.name: 'other-table',
      }, <...>
    ],
    table3 : [
      {
        table3.id: 1,
        table3.name: 'something else'
      }, <...>
    ]
  }
]
```

Is there a query or function with which I can achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after a lot of trial and error I found a similar solution:

```sql
SELECT table1.*, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT table1_table2.id SEPARATOR ",") AS table2_ids, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT table1_table3.id SEPARATOR ",") AS table3_ids FROM table1 LEFT JOIN table1_table2 ON table1.id = table1_table2.id LEFT JOIN table1_table3 ON table1.id = table1_table3.id WHERE GROUP BY tabl1.id;
```

This will return

```js
[
  {
    id: 1, // id from table1
    name: 'my-table-name-from-table-1', // name from table1
    table2_ids: '1,2,3 ...', // ids from table1_table2
    table3_ids: '1,2,4, ...' // ids from table1_table3
  }
  <...>
]
```